# Using loops to set layout dimensions R

Tags: r

I am not sure this is possible. Basically what I'm trying to do is create a plot loop where if more than 5 plots are to be plotted then a second row of plots should be done ncol = to 5- number of plots.

```
data=matrix(rbinom(10*1000, 1, .5), ncol=10)

subdata1 = data[1:5,]
subdata2 = data[1:7,]

if (nrow(subdata1) <= 5){
  par(mfrow = c(1, nrow(subdata1)))
  for (i in 1:nrow(subdata1)){
    plot(as.numeric(subdata1[i,1:5]), as.numeric(subdata1[i,6:10]))
    } 
  }else{
  ## need to figure out how to bind layout based on nrows
  ## i.e. subdata2
  return(NULL)
}
```

Basically I'm building a shinny app where based on users selections there could be anywhere from 1 plot to 10 and I want to be able to display this as nice as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be as nice as possible perhaps you should look at the easy option of using the `n2mfrow()` function. This takes a number and turns it into the best row/column combination. With your example you can do `par(mfrow = n2mfrow(nrow(data)))` before running your for-loop plot. However, this will not fix the plots to 5 columns.

Comment: Brilliant option! Thank you @Evan

Comment: Happy to have helped ~